# Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows were affected by update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm inserting (or trying to) one record into a table using the following trigger:

```
create trigger kv_trg_AssetAdjustment_AW 
on _btblInvoiceLines        --select * from _btblInvoiceLines
with encryption
after insert, update
as
    if (select trigger_nestlevel(object_id('kv_trg_AssetAdjustment_AW'))) > 1
         return
begin
    declare @Asset      varchar(40)
    ,       @Desc       varchar(100)
    ,       @AssetValue float
    ,       @Price      float
    ,       @Qty        float
    ,       @Code       varchar(100)
    ,       @Valid      int
    ,       @Exists     int
    ,       @SL         int
    ,       @NextNum    int
    ,       @Variable   varchar(100)
    ,       @NewCode    varchar(100)
    ,       @Err        nvarchar(500)

    select  @Err    =   '--------------------------';
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   'Please specify a hyphen ("-") between Item Code & Description in the Description!';

    if exists(select cDescription from inserted where cDescription  like '%-%')
        select  @Valid  =   1
    else
    begin
        raiserror(@Err, 16, 1)
        return;
    end

    select
        @Asset      =   ulIDPOrdTxGLVAT
    ,   @Code       =   LEFT(cDescription, CHARINDEX('-', cDescription) - 1)
    ,   @Desc       =   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(cDescription, CHARINDEX('-', cDescription), LEN(cDescription)), '-', '')
    ,   @AssetValue =   fQuantityLineTotExcl
    ,   @Qty        =   fQuantity
    from    inserted

    if exists(select Code from StkItem where Code = @Code)
        select  @Exists =   1
    else
        select  @Exists =   0

    select  @Variable   =   (select substring(@Code,1,len(@Code)-1))
    select  @NextNum    =   (select max(RIGHT(@Code,1))+1 from StkItem where Code like (@Variable + '%'))
    select  @NewCode    =   substring(@Code,1,len(@Code)-1) + cast(@NextNum as varchar)

    begin
        if  (@Asset = 'Asset')
        begin
            if  (@Exists = 0)
            begin
                insert into StkItem (
                                Code
                        ,       cSimpleCode
                        ,       Description_1
                        ,       Description_2
                        ,       TTI
                        ,       TTC
                        ,       TTG
                        ,       TTR
                        ,       WhseItem
                        ,       ubIIAsset
                                                )
                        select  @Code
                        ,       @Code
                        ,       @Desc
                        ,       @AssetValue
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        insert into StkItem     (
                                Code
                        ,       cSimpleCode
                        ,       Description_1
                        ,       Description_2
                        ,       TTI
                        ,       TTC
                        ,       TTG
                        ,       TTR
                        ,       WhseItem
                        ,       ubIIAsset
                                                )
                        select  @NewCode
                        ,       @NewCode
                        ,       @Desc
                        ,       @AssetValue
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                        ,       1
                    end
            end
            begin
                update  _btblInvoiceLines
                    set ufIDPOrdTxGLAssetValue          =   @AssetValue
                from    _btblInvoiceLines   L
                join    inserted on L.idInvoiceLines    =   inserted.idInvoiceLines
            end
    end
END;
go
```

The record I'm inserting is into StkItem.

On this table I have a second trigger which fires after insert.

This trigger links this record (Stock Item) to all warehouses.

When I run these triggers separately, they work, but they do not want to work together.

I did notice that Trigger one adds more than one item, which I'm not sure if that is what is causing the problem.

Check code for second trigger:

```
set ansi_nulls on
go

set quoted_identifier on
go

set nocount on
go

create trigger kv_trg_LinkAssetToAllWhses_AW on StkItem
with encryption
after insert, update
as

if trigger_nestlevel() > 5
     return

begin

    declare @SL         int
    ,       @Asset      int
    ,       @Loop       int
    ,       @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)

    declare @WHs table
    (
            ID int identity primary key,
            WhseID int
    )

    insert into @WHs (WhseID)
    select WhseLink from WhseMst
    order by WhseLink

    select  @SL         =   StockLink
    ,       @Asset      =   ubIIAsset
    from    inserted

    if  (@Asset =   1)
        begin
            select @Loop = min(ID) FROM @WHs
            while @Loop IS NOT NULL
            begin
                set @sqlCommand = 'exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 '+cast(@SL as varchar)+','+cast((select WhseID from @WHs where ID = @Loop) as varchar)+',0,0,1'
                exec(@sqlCommand)
                select @Loop = min(ID) FROM @WHs where ID>@Loop
            end
        end
end
go
```

I've searched all over the internet for a solution, but couldn't find anything pertaining to my exact problem.

I managed to narrow my problem down to the second trigger.

However, the second trigger executes a stored procedure which I did not develop.

Is there a problem with my second trigger or is it the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[_bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH] @StockID int, @WhseID int, @IsDefaultWH bit, @AllowNegative bit, @iBranchID int = 0

AS

Set nocount on
Begin tran
Declare @SPError int
  if (not exists (select * from WhseStk where WHWhseID=@WhseID and WHStockLink=@StockID)) begin
    --Add to WhseStk
    insert into WhseStk (WHWhseID, WHStockLink, bWHAllowNegStock, WhseStk_iBranchID)
    values (@WhseID, @StockID, @AllowNegative, @iBranchID)
    set @SPError = @@ERROR
    if @SPError <> 0 goto AbortTran
    if ((select top 1 bCostPerWarehouse from stdftbl where IsNull(StDfTbl_iBranchID,0)=0) = 1) begin
      exec _espPriceUtilGetItemDef @StockId, @WhseID
    end
  end
goto CommitTran
AbortTran:
  rollback tran
  RAISERROR (@SPError, 16, 1)
  return @SPError
CommitTran:
  commit tran
  return 0
GO
```

Thanks for your assistance so far.

Comment: Tip: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Re: `cast(@SL as varchar)` and other cases. From [`VarChar(n)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "When _n_ is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When _n_ is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." The best practice is to _always_ specify a length.

Comment: This will never work. The procedure you are using attempts to manage its own transaction - therefore it will not work once it is executed "inside" of another transaction. That will causing nested transactions which the application (presumably - "does not work" is not a useful problem description) is not expecting and does not handle correctly. to be continued.

Comment: The path you have taken will develop into a rat's nest and become a monster. Go back and redesign the process. Currently you insert into one table causing a trigger to insert into another table causing a trigger to execute a stored procedure which also execute a stored procedure - and now you're in the labyrinth. It started out as a simple idea but it turns out that there are various things to consider during these updates. to be continued

Comment: Worse - your triggers assume a single row is inserted/updated. If you want to code that way, then you should enforce it within the triggers to avoid problems with the logic not working as intended when multiple rows are affected. Lastly, the if statement in the procedure is **highly** questionable. TOP without an order by clause is a problem. That statement selects rows where ibranchid is null or zero - is it based on an assumption that zero will never by found in that column? That only one row will have a null value? to be continued

Comment: Given the name, perhaps those assumptions are ok - FOR NOW. Without constraints (and documentation) these are the sort of things that one might change over time without considering (or knowing) the impact. Here in this procedure, one might or might now see a negative impact - it just depends on which row the query uses for the comparison at any given point in time. That's a lot to throw at you - but I've been on the back side of this type of design though it was nested much deeper. As a consultant hired to fix the process.

Comment: And two more things - your trigger allows the value of description to be just a single hyphen. Be careful how you enforce rules - someone will eventually try and find this. "With encryption" has little value and is easily reversible. It's really "obfuscation", not "encryption".

Comment: "The path you have taken will develop into a rat's nest and become a monster. Go back and redesign the process. Currently you insert into one table causing a trigger to insert into another table causing a trigger to execute a stored procedure which also execute a stored procedure - and now you're in the labyrinth. It started out as a simple idea but it turns out that there are various things to consider during these updates. to be continued "

Thanks SMor, however, you advise I should go back and redesign. How would you suggest I do that?